# How to analytically prove that $x=2ln\frac{3}{2}$ is the absolute maximum value of $f(x)=3e^{\frac{1}{2}x}-e^x$?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the maximum value that $f(x)=3e^{\frac{1}{2}x}-e^x$ takes on all it's domain $(-\infty, \infty)$?
I've found a critical point at $x=2ln\frac{3}{2}$ and by plotting the function I deduce there's the maximum, but I don't know how to prove it analytically, (I know how to prove this point is a local maximum but not the global) please help me :'(

Comment: Here's a general recipe: A global maxima may lie at any critical point ($f' = 0$, or the derivative doesn't exist), or at the boundary of the domain. Since the domain is unbounded, you can test the limits $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$. If either of these is unbounded above, or converge to a value greater than any local maxima, the function doesn't have a global maxima. Otherwise, the highest local maxima is the global maxima.

Comment: If you showed that we have a local max there the right way, by examining the sign of the first derivative, then you have also shown there is a global max there. If you showed local max by using the second derivative, then you end up with less knowledge of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

Put $q(x) = e^{x/2}$, $g(x) = x(3-x)$. Then $f(x) = q(x)(3 - q(x)) = g(q(x)).$

The function $g$ achieves a global maximum at $x = 3/2$ so $f$ achieves a global maximum at $q^{-1}(3/2) = 2\log(3/2)$.  No calculus is required here.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply: the function $t=\mathrm e^{\frac12 x}$ is an increasing function of $x$. So, it amounts to the same to find the maxima of $3\mathrm e^{\frac12 x}-\mathrm e^x=3t-t^2=t(3-t)$.

Now this is a quadratic function $t$. As the coefficient ot $t^2$ is negative, it does have one maximum, attained for $t=$ the arithmetic mean of the roots, i.e. for $t=\dfrac32$.

Hence the given function attains a maximum for $x$ such that
$$\mathrm e^{\frac12 x}=\frac32\iff x=2\ln\frac32.$$